# Facebook Share function not working

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

When I click share button alert("enter") shows its access to the else part but after that it showing "An error occurred while sharing this diary on Facebook".Facebook connection all are working perfectly.Please help me to solve this problem .Thanks in advance

```
$scope.share = function(detail){
            alert("share");
            if(!FbShare.getFbDataShare())
            {
                ngFB.init({appId: '****************'});
                ngFB.login({
                    scope: 'email'
                }).then(function(response){
                    if(response.status === 'connected'){
                        FbShare.setFbDataShare(response.authResponse.accessToken);
                        $scope.share(detail);
                    }else{
                        $cordovaToast.showLongCenter("Facebook login failed");
                    }
                });
            }else{
                alert("enter");
                alert(detail.title);


                ngFB.api({
                    method: 'POST',
                    path: '/me/feed',
                    params: {
                        message: "From My Diary",
                        name: detail.title,
                        description: detail.description

                    }
                }).then(function(){
                    alert("The diary was shared on Facebook");

                }, function(){
                   alert("An error occurred while sharing this diary on Facebook");

                });
            }

        }
```

Comment: Log the actual API response to console, and see what it says.

Comment: Actually I found it thank you ....The code line should be " scope: 'email,publish_actions' " not like  " scope: 'email' "